# Mongoose - Model.find({}) is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am following a nodejs and mongoose tutorial and the only way i can query the collection is via the `.collection` property. Every tutorial i see, says `Model.find()` or `Model.findOne()` are legal but i keep getting the same error.

My model and schema are defined in the same file. i.e

```
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
    review: { type: String, required: true }
});

var collectionName = "fruit";
const f = mongoose.model(collectionName, fruitSchema);

const fruit = new f({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Pretty solid as a fruit."
});

fruit.save();
```

I have populated above `fruits` collection with 5 documents. But struggling to query the model directly:

`fruit.Find({}, callback);`

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `find` is a method of the model so you need to your model `f` instead of `fruit`

```js
var cursor = f.find();
```

Documentation for reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `find` method on a Mongoose's model. In this case, `f`. `fruit` is just a document and it doesn't have the `find` method.

Try replacing:

```
var cursor = fruit.find({});
```

by:

```
var cursor = f.find({});
```